# Sum of values per day in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions

My table:

```
Dataid  date        register_type  read_value
77      2012-08-15  gen            20
77      2012-08-15  solar          48
77      2012-08-16  gen            39
77      2012-08-16  gen            22
80      2012-07-11  gen            11
80      2012-07-12  id             23
91      2012-02-01  id              4
91      2012-02-01  gen            59
91      2012-02-08  gen            18
```

I would like, for each day, to do the sum of the `read_values` for only the "gen" `register_type`. I basically want the query to return the following table:

```
dataid  date        daily_value
77      2012-08-15  20.00
77      2012-08-16  61.00
80      2012-07-11  11.00
91      2012-02-01  59.00
91      2012-02-08  18.00
```

I tried the following query, but it does not work:

```
select 
    dataid, 
    date_trunc('day', timestamp_localtime) as truncated_day,
    substring(cast(date_trunc('day', timestamp_localtime) as text)
              from 1 for 10) as date,            
    sum(read_value) as daily_gen
where register_type like ‘%gen%’
from table
group by dataid, date_trunc('day', timestamp_localtime) 
order by dataid, truncated_day
```

How would I write this query?

Answer (score 5):

Works in Postgres:

```
SELECT dataid, date, sum(read_value) AS daily_value
FROM   tbl
WHERE  register_type = 'gen'
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,2
```

Or is your column named `date` actually something else than a date?
If it's actually a `timestamp`, replace `date` in my query with `date::date` (casting the `timestamp` to `date`) and it should work.
(You shouldn't use [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like `date` as identifiers to begin with, even if Postgres allows it.)

Comment: actually, my column is originally named timestamp_localtime. But I truncated it into truncated_date( then just YYYY_mm_dd). Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, the following would work:

```
SELECT SUM(read_value) AS daily_value, dataid, date
FROM (SELECT *, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date,105) AS newdate FROM Table)
WHERE type = 'gen'
GROUP BY newdate
```

For MySQL, use this instead:

```
SELECT SUM(read_value) AS daily_value, dataid, date
FROM (SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(newdate, '%d-%m-%Y') AS day FROM Table)
WHERE type = 'gen'
GROUP BY newdate
```

The subquery is required since `GROUP BY` doesn't support the usual aggregate functions. This, however, is needed only if `date` is a datetime. If its just a date, then there's no need to extract the *just the date* from it.